# Как привязать сетку бутстрапа к ширине блока в котором находиться элемент а не к ширине экрана?

Tags: html5, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Я написал виджет (независимый блок со своими стилями итд), фронт у него на бутстрапе. Когда вставляешь его на полную ширину страницы на сайте - все нормально. Он адаптируеться под ширину экрана  переносит строки итд. Но вот в чем проблема, если этот виджет вставить на основном сайте, скажем, в col-2 виджет будет смотреть на ширину экрана и располагаться в 2 столбца а по факту должен располагаться в 1. Можно ли как-то внутри кода независимого элемента сделать привязку именно к ширине контейнера, что бы сетка бутстрапа смотрела на ширину именно контейнера а не ширину монитора юзера?

Comment: Стили `col-` итак привязаны к ширине контейнера, поскольку выражены в `%`. Без кода примера сложно сказать что у вас не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, element query пока в стандарте css нет и они не поддерживаются никакими бразерами, а значит, при помощи бутстрапа добиться желаемого эффекта не получится.

Следует пересмотреть свою вёрстку и добиться желаемого поведения без использования media-запросов. На самом деле, инструментов полно, особенно часто недообценивают float'ы и поведение inline-block'ов, а также позиционирование относительно них. Ну и flex'ы с grid'ами никто не отменял.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то внутри виджета нужно делать новый row с вложенным col, тогда пропорции будут привязываться уже к стилям виджета

Comment: Я не так выразиля, мне нужно привязать @media запросы к ширине блока а не к ширине экрана

Comment: Это не поможет.